# Perl: Use of reference "HASH(0x13bd718)" as array index at

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I'm writing a script to implement game 2048 to practice perl, and an error pops up occationally as something like this:

**Use of reference "HASH(0x13bd718)" as array index at 2048.pl line 181,  line 11.**

The code involved is for a subroutine like this:

```
sub gen1{
  my @free_locs = {};
  my $length;
  my $rand_loc;
  my $insert_loc;
  for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++){ 
    if($all_lines[$i] == 0){push @free_locs, $i;}
  }
  $length = @free_locs;
  $rand_loc = int rand $length;
  if ($rand_loc == $length) {$rand_loc--;}
  $insert_loc = $free_locs[$rand_loc];
  $all_lines[$insert_loc] = &generate();
  &row_update;
  &col_update;
}
```

At first I was writing that like as

```
$all_lines[$free_locs[$rand_loc]] = &generate();
```

The error seems to pop up more often. Then I switched to the code in the subroutine shown above, which seems to reduce the chance for it to happen, but it still happens...

Is there anything wrong with my way of coding here? What's the cleanest way of writing such piece of code?

Thanks and regards,

Terry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my @free_locs = {};` declares `@free_locs` to be a one-element array whose first element is a reference to an empty hash (`{}`).  Thus, whenever `$rand_loc` is 0, `$insert_loc` will be a hash, and trying to use that hash as an index in `$all_lines[$insert_loc]` produces the error.  To declare `@free_locs` as an empty array, write either `my @free_locs = ();` or just `my @free_locs;`.

Comment: Yeah i realized that later myself but didn't know the reason behind it... Thanks a lot for your explanation!